# XML to XML xsl style sheet

Tags: xml, xslt

I've been given the task to look into using xsl to update a few of our xml documents at work, and I have been looking at some tutorials for xsl, though I have yet to come across what I would ideally be looking for...

Since im not at work, wheres a small example of heres what im looking for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application>
    <id>627</id>
    <name>application1</name>
    <url>www.application.com</url>
</application>
```

I would need to convert this to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application>
    <id>627</id>
    <application_name>application1</application_name>
    <url>www.application.com</url>
</application>
```

Now from the examples and tutorials I've seen I could do this with a hard coded xsl sheet looking like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <application>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </application>
    </xsl:template> 
    <xsl:template match="id">
        <id>
        <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </id>
     </xsl:template>
     <xsl:template match="name">
        <application_name>
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </application_name>
     </xsl:template>
     <xsl:template match="url">
        <url>
        <xsl:value-of select="url"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </url>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this really wouldnt be practical since we have near 50 different xml documents that might need changing, and so I was really looking for a catch all template that I can use, and then only override the appropriate element that needs to be changed.

Does this functionality exist in xsl?

Comment: If you need to update 50 docs of XML to change a node name, you would probably be better off writing something to enumerate the files, load them into an XmlReader and stream them back out using an XmlWriter.

Comment: can't you just use a text editor if it's just an element name change? edit - find/replace all - save as...

Comment: But wouldnt that involve having to write the code for each xml document, and also document version, if in future the xml becomes out of date with the code base again.   Using xsl would be the "simplier" option since I could have an xsl sheet for each xml document, and process that when it gets imported into our application

Comment: @iandayman  it wouldn't be practical/good to get uses to update the users to update the xml documents, I'm hoping that this could be done automatic, hence the looking into xsl

Comment: @user612072 i see. thought it was a one-off exercise - sorry my xsl too rusty :)

Comment: @user612072: You can edit your own question to fix the slashes, you can also delete your comment about those slashes to help tidy things up a bit.

Comment: @Duncan-Howe: If you use an XSLT processor like Saxon, you know that it can take a set of xml files to process in batch using the same stylesheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me see if I understand what you need. The first template rule in the transform below is called *identity transform* processes all *nodes* by copying them, and can be overridden for individual elements, attributes, comments, processing instructions, or text nodes. In your case, I've just overridden for the element `name`.

---

**XSLT 1.0** tested under **Saxon 6.5.5**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="name">
        <xsl:variable name="parent" select="name(parent::*[1])"/>
        <xsl:variable name="node" select="local-name()"/>
        <xsl:element name="{$parent}_{$node}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied on this input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<anyapplication>
    <id>627</id>
    <name>application1</name>
    <url>www.application.com</url>
</anyapplication>
```

Produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<anyapplication>
    <id>627</id>
    <anyapplication_name>application1</anyapplication_name>
    <url>www.application.com</url>
</anyapplication>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
     <xsl:template match="name">
        <application_name>
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </application_name>
     </xsl:template>
     <xsl:template match="not(name)">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: > Error in expression not(name): The only functions allowed in a pattern are id() and key()

Comment: Oh - sorry - this should work for you: 'node()[not(self::name)]'

Comment: It's still wrong, the body of the template processes the input twice. The standard identity template is so well known, I'm surprised to see it being reinvented incorrectly.